# Ninject WCF bootstrapper registering multiple services

Tags: c#, wcf, ninject

I'm having a problem getting the wcf extensions to work with more than one self host bootstrapper. With one my services are created by ninject fine (per call), but when I add another I get an exception that the ChannelDispatcher is unable to open its IChannelListener, the inner exception states that a registration already eixsts for URI 'net.tcp://localhost:901/MyService'.

My registration code looks like this:

```
var myService= NinjectWcfConfiguration.Create<MyService, NinjectServiceSelfHostFactory>();
_myServiceHost= new NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper(() => _kernel, myService);

var myService2= NinjectWcfConfiguration.Create<MyService2, NinjectServiceSelfHostFactory>();
_myService2Host= new NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper(() => _kernel, myService2);

_myServiceHost.Start();
_myService2Host.Start();
```

Both services have the correct sections in the config file and they both have different endpoint URIs with different ports. The same config works fine if I wire all of this up manually.

Does anyone have a clue here? Bit stumped...

Cheers

Comment: did you ever fix your issue? as I happen to get this issue myself.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I didn't get around to solving this in the end unfortunately, other work got in the way and then we ended up switching to AutoFac rather than Ninject.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue just now, the solution is to have one Bootstrapper with all configurations in its params:

```
var myService= NinjectWcfConfiguration.Create<MyService, NinjectServiceSelfHostFactory>();
var myService2= NinjectWcfConfiguration.Create<MyService2, NinjectServiceSelfHostFactory>();

_myServicesHost= new NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper(() => _kernel, myService, myService2);

_myServicesHost.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use separate Kernel for each NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper instance

```
var myService= NinjectWcfConfiguration.Create<MyService, NinjectServiceSelfHostFactory>();
_myServiceHost= new NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper(() => new StandardKernel(YourInjectionModule), myService);

var myService2= NinjectWcfConfiguration.Create<MyService2, NinjectServiceSelfHostFactory>();
_myService2Host= new NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper(() => new StandardKernel(YourInjectionModule), myService2);

_myServiceHost.Start();
_myService2Host.Start();
```

Also, when you dispose NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper `_myServiceHost.Dispose()` its Kernel will also be disposed. So if you use your kernel somewhere else you will run into problems.